# Image capture from camera and gallery in swift

Tags: swift3, camera

I am trying to get image from camera and show in imageview using swift 3.0 but it is showing white background only. Image is uploaded to my server successfully. On iPAD it is not even opening the camera app. below is my code: I am new to swift to please let me know what mistake i ma doing.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import AlamofireImage
class RadiologyViewController:UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UITextViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var indicator1: UIActivityIndicatorView!
@IBOutlet weak var name  : UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var mobile: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var gender: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var age   : UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var indicator4: UIActivityIndicatorView!
@IBOutlet weak var indicator3: UIActivityIndicatorView!
@IBOutlet weak var indicator2: UIActivityIndicatorView!

@IBOutlet weak var pic4text: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var pic3text: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var pic2text: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var pictext1: UITextView!

// WHICH SHOW BUTTON YOU WANT TO SHOW YOU HAVE TO CHANGE HEIGHT CONSTRAINT //
// conPic1height = conPic1height - 20 - UN HIDE BUTTON BY TAKING ITS OUTLET// 
@IBOutlet weak var conPic1height: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var conPic2height: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var conPic3height: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var conPic4height: NSLayoutConstraint!

@IBOutlet weak var pic4: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pic3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pic2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pic1: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var complain: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var explain : UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var date    : UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var btnShowPic4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btnShowPic3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btnShowPic2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btnShowPic1: UIButton!
var patient : Patients? = nil;
var username : String?  = nil;

var picNumber : Int   = 0;
var pic1path : String = "";
var pic2path : String = "";
var pic3path : String = "";
var pic4path : String = "";

var strLabel   = UILabel()
var indicator  = UIActivityIndicatorView()
let effectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .dark))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    if patient != nil {
        name.text     = patient?.patientName;
        age.text      = "Age: "+(patient?.patientAge)!;
        gender.text   = "Gender: "+(patient?.patientGender)!;
        mobile.text   = "Mobile: "+(patient?.patientMobile)!;
        date.text     = "Date: "+(patient?.patientDate)!;
        complain.text = "Complaint: " + "\(self.makeComplainText(complain: (patient?.patientComplaint)!))";
        explain.text  = "Explain: "+(patient?.patientExplainComplaint)!;
    }

    let defaults1 = UserDefaults.standard
    let user = defaults1.object(forKey: "user") as? NSData
    let responseData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: user! as Data) as? ResponseModel

    if responseData != nil {
        if responseData?.profile != nil {
             username = responseData?.profile[0].userName;
        }
    }
    pictext1.delegate = self
    pic2text.delegate = self
    pic3text.delegate = self
    pic4text.delegate = self

    pic1path = (patient?.patientPic1)!;
    pic2path = (patient?.patientPic2)!;
    pic3path = (patient?.patientPic3)!;
    pic4path = (patient?.patientPic4)!;

    pictext1.text = patient?.patientPictxt1;
    pic2text.text = patient?.patientPictxt2;
    pic3text.text = patient?.patientPictxt3;
    pic4text.text = patient?.patientPictxt4;

    let tapFirstGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped1(_:)))
    pic1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    pic1.addGestureRecognizer(tapFirstGestureRecognizer)

    let tapSecondGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped2(_:)))
    pic2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    pic2.addGestureRecognizer(tapSecondGestureRecognizer)

    let tapThirdGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped3(_:)))
    pic3.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    pic3.addGestureRecognizer(tapThirdGestureRecognizer)

    let tapFourGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped4(_:)))
    pic4.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    pic4.addGestureRecognizer(tapFourGestureRecognizer)

    if patient?.patientPic1 != "" {
        pic1.image = nil;
        setImage(imageview: pic1, url: (patient?.patientPic1)!,indicator:indicator1)
        showFirstButton(show: false)
    } else {
        showFirstButton(show: true)
        indicator1.isHidden = true
    }

    if patient?.patientPic2 != "" {
        pic2.image = nil;
        showSecondButton(show: false)
        setImage(imageview: pic2, url: (patient?.patientPic2)!,indicator:indicator2)
    } else {
        showSecondButton(show: true)
        indicator2.isHidden = true
    }

    if patient?.patientPic3 != "" {
        pic3.image = nil;
        showThreeButton(show: false)
        setImage(imageview: pic3, url: (patient?.patientPic3)!,indicator:indicator3)
    } else {
        showThreeButton(show: true)
        indicator3.isHidden = true
    }

    if patient?.patientPic4 != "" {
        pic4.image = nil;
        showFourButton(show: false)
        setImage(imageview: pic4, url: (patient?.patientPic4)!,indicator:indicator4)
    } else {
        showFourButton(show: true)
        indicator4.isHidden = true
    }

    let tapKeuboardDismissGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard(_:)))
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapKeuboardDismissGestureRecognizer)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

  func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text == "\n"  // Recognizes enter key in keyboard
    {
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    return true
}

func dismissKeyboard(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    view.endEditing(true)

}

func imageTapped1(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if (sender.view as? UIImageView) != nil {
        print("Image Tapped")
        picNumber = 1;
        showActionSheet()
    }
}

func imageTapped2(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if (sender.view as? UIImageView) != nil {
        print("Image Tapped")
        picNumber = 2;
        showActionSheet()
    }
}

func imageTapped3(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if (sender.view as? UIImageView) != nil {
        print("Image Tapped")
        picNumber = 3;
        showActionSheet()
    }
}

func imageTapped4(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if (sender.view as? UIImageView) != nil {
        print("Image Tapped")
        picNumber = 4;
        showActionSheet()
    }
}

func camera()
{
    let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    myPickerController.delegate = self;
    myPickerController.allowsEditing = false
    myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
    myPickerController.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
    myPickerController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func photoLibrary()
{

    let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    myPickerController.delegate = self;
    myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

    self.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}



func showActionSheet() {
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (alert:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        self.camera()
    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (alert:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        self.photoLibrary()
    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))

 //            if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad) {
 //            let popover = actionSheet.popoverPresentationController
 //            popover?.sourceRect = self.view.bounds
 //            popover?.sourceView = self.pic1
 //            popover?.permittedArrowDirections = .any
 //            self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
 //        } else {
        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    //}
}

@IBAction func btnpic3Click(_ sender: Any) {
    var profileStoryBoard: UIStoryboard!
    profileStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name:"\(Helper.manageStoryBoardName())ShowImage",bundle: nil)
    let viewcontroller : ImageShowViewController = profileStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ImageShowViewController") as! ImageShowViewController
    viewcontroller.url = pic3path
    self.present(viewcontroller, animated: false)
}

@IBAction func btnpic4Click(_ sender: Any) {
    var profileStoryBoard: UIStoryboard!
    profileStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name:"\(Helper.manageStoryBoardName())ShowImage",bundle: nil)
    let viewcontroller : ImageShowViewController = profileStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ImageShowViewController") as! ImageShowViewController
    viewcontroller.url = pic4path
    self.present(viewcontroller, animated: false)
}
@IBAction func btnpic1Click(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var profileStoryBoard: UIStoryboard!
    profileStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name:"\(Helper.manageStoryBoardName())ShowImage",bundle: nil)
    let viewcontroller : ImageShowViewController = profileStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ImageShowViewController") as! ImageShowViewController
    viewcontroller.url = pic1path
    self.present(viewcontroller, animated: false)
}
@IBAction func btnpic2Click(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var profileStoryBoard: UIStoryboard!
    profileStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name:"\(Helper.manageStoryBoardName())ShowImage",bundle: nil)
    let viewcontroller : ImageShowViewController = profileStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ImageShowViewController") as! ImageShowViewController
    viewcontroller.url = pic2path
    self.present(viewcontroller, animated: false)
}
 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    if picNumber == 1 {
        pic1.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        uploadImage(image: (info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage)!)
    } else if picNumber == 2 {
        pic2.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        uploadImage(image: (info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage)!)
    } else if picNumber == 3 {
        pic3.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        uploadImage(image: (info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage)!)
    } else {
        pic4.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        uploadImage(image: (info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage)!)
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func uploadImage(image:UIImage) -> Void {
    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
    self.showLoading(title: "uploding image");
    let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.2)!
    var path :String = "";
    let parameters = ["username": username]

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "images",fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.append((value?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)!, withName: key)
        }
        },
                     to:"http://www.dentalsa.net/api/api.php?method=radiaolog_image_update")
    { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                self.hideLoading()
                let value = response.result.value
                let jsonResponse = JSON(value)
                let status = jsonResponse["status"].stringValue
                let message = jsonResponse["message"].stringValue
                if status == "false" {
                     self.showAlerError(titleText: "Error", messagetext: message);
                }
                path = jsonResponse["path"].stringValue
                if self.picNumber == 1 {
                    self.pic1path = path
                } else if self.picNumber == 2 {
                    self.pic2path = path
                } else if self.picNumber == 3 {
                    self.pic3path = path
                } else if self.picNumber == 4 {
                    self.pic4path = path
                }
                print("ImagePath"+path)
            }

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)  
        }
    }
    } else {
         self.showAlerError(titleText: "Error", messagetext: "Please check Internet connectivity");
    }

}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func makeComplainText(complain:String) -> String {
    let characters = Array(complain.characters);
    var data="";

    if characters[0] == "1" {
        data += "Check-Up, ";
    }
    if characters[1] == "1" {
        data += "Teeth Cleaning, ";
    }
    if characters[2] == "1" {
        data += "Periodontal Treatment, ";
    }
    if characters[3] == "1" {
        data += "Dental Fillings, ";
    }
    if characters[4] == "1" {
        data += "Prothesis, ";
    }
    if characters[5] == "1" {
        data += "Extraction, ";
    }
    if characters[6] == "1" {
        data += "Hollywoods smile, ";
    }
    if characters[7] == "1" {
        data += "Children's Teeth, ";
    }
    if characters[8] == "1" {
        data += "Bleaching, ";
    }
    return data;
}

@IBAction func saveClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let netowrk = NetworkCall();
    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
        self.showLoading(title: "Please wait")
    netowrk.radiologyUpdate(username: username!,patientId: (patient?.patientID)!,picText1: pictext1.text!,picText2: pic2text.text!,picText3: pic3text.text!,picText4: pic4text.text!,pic1:pic1path,pic2:pic2path,pic3:pic3path,pic4:pic4path) { responseObject in
        self.hideLoading()
        if responseObject.status == "true" {

            print("Success view controller");
            self.showAlerError(titleText: "Success", messagetext: "Details saved Successfully");
        } else {
            self.showAlerError(titleText: "Error", messagetext: responseObject.message!);
        }

        return
    }
} else {
self.showAlerError(titleText: "Error", messagetext: "Please check Internet connectivity");
}
}
func showLoading(title: String) {

    strLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    indicator.removeFromSuperview()
    effectView.removeFromSuperview()

    strLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 0, width: 160, height: 46))
    strLabel.text = title
    strLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFontWeightMedium)
    strLabel.textColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 0.7)

    effectView.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.midX - strLabel.frame.width/2, y: view.frame.midY - strLabel.frame.height/2 , width: 160, height: 46)
    effectView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    effectView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .white)
    indicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 46, height: 46)
    indicator.startAnimating()

    effectView.addSubview(indicator)
    effectView.addSubview(strLabel)
    view.addSubview(effectView)
}

func setImage(imageview :UIImageView,url:String,indicator:UIActivityIndicatorView) -> Void {
    Alamofire.request("http://www.dentalsa.net"+url).responseImage { response in

        if let image = response.result.value {
            indicator.isHidden = true
            imageview.image = image
        }
    }
}

func hideLoading() {
    self.effectView.removeFromSuperview()
    //indicator.stopAnimating()
}

func showAlerError(titleText:String,messagetext:String) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: titleText, message:
        messagetext, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,handler: nil))

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


@IBAction func backClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
   _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

func showFirstButton(show :Bool){
    //conPic1height.constant = 150
    btnShowPic1.isHidden = show
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

func showSecondButton(show :Bool){
    //conPic1height.constant = 150
    btnShowPic2.isHidden = show
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

func showThreeButton(show :Bool){
    //conPic1height.constant = 150
    btnShowPic3.isHidden = show
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

func showFourButton(show :Bool){
    //conPic1height.constant = 150
    btnShowPic4.isHidden = show
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

I need to capture image from camera and gallery on both iphone and iPad. I don't know what is the issue which i am facing here.